# Simple queries occasionally running very slowly

Tags: postgresql, performance-tuning

I have some very simple queries that occasionally run very slowly.

The table viewed_sites has about 10 - 20 rows.

Running EXPLAIN ANALYZE always gives a runtime of less than 3 milliseconds.

When the query is run automatically (every 10 seconds) it occasionally takes over a second to run.

The query:

```
INSERT INTO ga.viewed_sites (site_id) VALUES ('gop2')
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE viewed_sites (
    site_id character varying(4) NOT NULL,
    last_viewed timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);
```

The (occasional) log result:

`2010-05-24 15:47:55 UTC LOG:  duration: 1044.632 ms  statement: INSERT INTO ga.viewed_sites (site_id) VALUES ('gop2')`

It's a horribly vague question, but what could be causing this?  I suppose it comes down to CPU, RAM, HDD or some combination of the above.

Postgresql 8.3, Ubuntu 8.04

Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E6750  @ 2.66GHz

2 GiB RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, the table could be locked. Which seems all things given, more likely. Postgresql is very conservative about locks, but it can happen. A one second wait for HD write, or CPU seems extremely unlikely. And, it doesn't take much ram to do an insert. Check the table `pg_locks` (and `pg_stat_activity` to see what their doing), and the function `pg_lock_status()`, or some of the other tables and functions pertaining to lock status.

Comment: Is there a way to log table locks? The chances of the lock being active when I look at those tables is slim.

Answer (score 1):

Does the table have a foreign key?  If it has to check the foreign key constraint, then it has to go do a table lookup.  Maybe that's slowing it down.

http://wiki.postgresql.org has a ton of tips.

Comment: It does have a foreign key, and a trigger.  I disabled both of these and it had no effect. Thanks for the wiki link though.